# How to check if database is returning NULL

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am using sqlite database with my app
following is my code which is getting data

```
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {


            NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

            [dataArray addObject:str1];



        }
```

this program crashed if there is null in database.

Actually i have multiple columns and i am saving data only to one column of  a row so other remain null, this creating problem...

can anyone tell me how to check if current value is null
i have tried to check if str1 is null here?
but prog crashes ....

thank you
please help

Comment: when database having null then control will not be enter in while so check at other place and put code where you get crash.

Comment: NO the control enters because the row exists..But the first column of the row is null here so crashed inside when assigning it to string...

Comment: if i am wrong....please tell how to check outside ....

Comment: No need to check outside : database is empty or not.

Comment: Ok where you get crash at addObject or before this.

Comment: @Ishu Gupta--at the line where i add value to string....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Code as follows,

```
if(sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0) != nil)
{
//Data exists
}
```